# Basic element rendering in ReactJS is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS.  I visited [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) in order to have some basic lessons.  After going through first lesson, I could write following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Hello world with date time in ReactJS</title>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="root"></div>


        <script type="text/jsx">

            const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
            ReactDOM.render(
              element,
              document.getElementById('root')
            );

        </script>


    </body>

</html>
```

But to my surprise, it is working [here](http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/rrpgNB?editors=1010) but not on my computer or at my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/orp64fyn/2/). Can you please show me why my code is not working?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `text/jsx`  to  `text/babel` . It works.

Comment: Is it possible that I can create another element say a link under above h1 element in the same div, because when I write another code under the above code, the previous element is not shown, why so?

Comment: @NizamuddinShaikh Please show your code in the fiddle.  `const element = <div>  < h1> Hello,world < /h1>  < h2> Hello,world.TOO < /h2> </div> ; ` I write this code in the fiddle. It show.

Comment: @NizamuddinShaikh  https://jsfiddle.net/orp64fyn/10  I create a new div element and change the second render at the new div.  In your code,  the second render replaces the first render.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have JSX processing enabled.
If you're using jsFiddle you can move your JS code to JavaScript edit section and click on settings button in top-right corner of this section and then select `Babel + JSX` from language select.

Comment: Yes Bartek you are right, the fiddle works after carrying out your above suggestions.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you throw some light on second question, please